# How to import a typescript module inside a Web Worker in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-worker

Since Angular 8, you can now generate web worker to your app from the CLI. I did so exactly like the official guide:

https://angular.io/guide/web-worker

And it works perfectly.

But as soon as I try to import any module to the top of `app.worker.ts` with:

```
import { MyData } from '../shared/shared.module';
```

Then I get compile errors:
[image]

Is there any other way to import modules into web workers?

Comment: Just as a comment that might be helpful, one thing I've noticed with web-workers in Angular 8 is that importing anything that is marked as @Injectable() causes exactly this sort of error. If your module has anything using DI that might be the cause of this error message. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution to that problem yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was that this shared module I was trying to import was created with `ng generate module`. In doing so, angular automatically imports `NgModule`, `CommonModule` and adds an `@NgModule` with declarations and imports to the exported class. These give you access to the DOM, and web workers cannot have access to the DOM. Which is what the compile error I was getting was talking about. Even tho I wasn't really using these imports and none of these were the reason why I was importing this module into the webworker. They were there anyway and they were causing the error.

I fixed it by simply removing the 2 import statements for `NgModule`, `CommonModule` and the whole `@NgModule` from my shared module. Then it imported fine without any errors into the web worker.

Comment: Thanks..I had similar problem and this pointed me in the correct direction.