# How to import a node module inside an angular web worker?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, web-worker, angular8

**I try to import a node module inside an [Angular 8 web worker](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker), but get an compile error 'Cannot find module'. Anyone know how to solve this?**

I created a new worker inside my electron project with `ng generate web-worker app`, like described in the above mentioned ng documentation.

All works fine until i add some import like `path` or `fs-extra` e.g.:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />    
import * as path from 'path';

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {    
  console.log(path.resolve('/'))
  const response = `worker response to ${data}`;
  postMessage(response);
});
```

This import works fine in any other ts component but inside the web worker i get a compile **error** with this message e.g.

```
Error: app/app.worker.ts:3:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'.
```

How can i fix this? Maybe i need some additional parameter in the generated `tsconfig.worker.json`?

To **reproduce** the error, run:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hoefling/stackoverflow-57774039
$ cd stackoverflow-57774039
$ yarn build
```

Or check out the project's [build log](https://travis-ci.org/hoefling/stackoverflow-57774039/jobs/581774748#L247) on Travis.

Note:

1) I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616120/how-to-import-a-typescript-module-inside-a-web-worker-in-angular-8) as a similar problem, but the answer handles only custom modules.

2) I tested the same import with a [minimal electron seed](https://github.com/trusktr/electron-web-worker-example) which uses web workers and it worked, but this example uses plain java script without angular.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### 1. TypeScript error

As you've noticed the first error is a TypeScript error. Looking at the `tsconfig.worker.json` I've found that it sets `types` to an empty array:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Specifying `types` turns off the [automatic inclusion of `@types` packages](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types). Which is a problem in this case because `path` has its type definitions in `@types/node`.

So let's fix that by explicitly adding `node` to the `types` array:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
        "node"
    ],
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

This fixes the TypeScript error, however trying to build again we're greeted with a very similar error. This time from Webpack directly.

### 2. Webpack error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.worker.ts (./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js!./src/app/app.worker.ts)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/worker-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in './src/app'
```

To figure this one out we need to dig quite a lot deeper...

#### Why it works everywhere else

First it's important to understand why importing `path` works in all the other modules. Webpack has the concept of [targets](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) (web, node, etc). Webpack uses this target to decide which default options and plugins to use.

Ordinarily the target of a Angular application using `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` would be `web`. However in your case, the `postinstall:electron` script actually patches `node_modules` to change that:

`postinstall.js` (parts omitted for brevity)

```js
const f_angular = 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js';

fs.readFile(f_angular, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  var result = data.replace(/target: "electron-renderer",/g, '');
  var result = result.replace(/target: "web",/g, '');
  var result = result.replace(/return \{/g, 'return {target: "electron-renderer",');

  fs.writeFile(f_angular, result, 'utf8');
});
```

The target [`electron-renderer`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#string) is treated by Webpack similarily to `node`. Especially interesting for us: It adds the [`NodeTargetPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/internal-plugins/#nodetargetplugin) by default.

What does that plugin do, you wonder? It adds all known built in Node.js modules as [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/). When building the application, Webpack will not attempt to bundle externals. Instead they are resolved using `require` at runtime. This is what makes importing `path` work, even though it's not installed as a module known to Webpack.

#### Why it doesn't work for the worker

The worker is compiled separately using the [`WorkerPlugin`](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin). In their [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin#plugins) they state:

> By default, `WorkerPlugin` doesn't run any of your configured Webpack plugins when bundling worker code - this avoids running things like `html-webpack-plugin twice`. For cases where it's necessary to apply a plugin to Worker code, use the `plugins` option.

Looking at the usage of `WorkerPlugin` deep within `@angular-devkit` we see the following:

`@angular-devkit/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/worker.js` (simplified)

```js
new WorkerPlugin({
    globalObject: false,
    plugins: [
        getTypescriptWorkerPlugin(wco, workerTsConfigPath)
    ],
})
```

As we can see it uses the `plugins` option, but only for a single plugin which is responsible for the TypeScript compilation. This way the default plugins, configured by Webpack, including `NodeTargetPlugin` get lost and are not used for the worker.

#### Solution

To fix this we have to modify the Webpack config. And to do that we'll use [`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack). Go ahead and install that package.

Next, open `angular.json` and update `projects > angular-electron > architect > build`:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
  "options": {
    "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
    }
    // existing options
  }
}
```

Repeat the same for `serve`.

Now, create `extra-webpack.config.js` in the same directory as `angular.json`:

```js
const WorkerPlugin = require('worker-plugin');
const NodeTargetPlugin = require('webpack/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin');

module.exports = (config, options) => {
  let workerPlugin = config.plugins.find(p => p instanceof WorkerPlugin);
  if (workerPlugin) {
    workerPlugin.options.plugins.push(new NodeTargetPlugin());
  }
  return config;
};
```

The file exports a function which will be called by `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` with the existing Webpack config object. We can then search all `plugins` for an instance of the `WorkerPlugin` and patch its options adding the `NodeTargetPlugin`.

Comment: Thx for your detailed answer. Indeed the compile error is gone and the app starts now, but the 'path' import is not working and fails with `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I searched for the error, but couldn't find any proper solution. Should i add any further plugin? Any idea?

Comment: You need to enable node integration in the worker. In `main.ts` where you create the  browser window, add `nodeIntegrationInWorker: true` under `webPreferences`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for both the solution and the in-depth explanation of the issue cause!

Comment: Ok, does anyone now about a similar solution for Electron with React. Ie. a more generic config example. I have succeeded getting a webworker bundled and running fine in the renderer. But had to use WP worker-loader plugin together with WP 5 to make bundling work with TS etc. I'm not that strong on WP configuration, and theres no references to the worker-loader plugin in my WP config. I'm searching for a way to configure it to use the NodeTargetPlugin somehow! Any help appreciated:-). Nb repro : https://github.com/mulgurul/ErbWithWebWorker/tree/WithWebWorkerOkButNoNode