# Use Web Worker to execute model.predict of tensorflowjs - Angular 11

Tags: angular, web-worker, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to execute the `model.predict` function inside a web worker and I can't find anywhere how can I import Tensorflowjs inside the web worker.

I can use the `importScripts('cdn')` but how can I reference to tensorflow to use it's functions?

This is the code up until now:

**worker.js**

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js');

addEventListener('message', async ({ data }) => {
  const model = data.model;
  const pred = await model.predict(data.tensor);
  postMessage(pred);
});
```

**service.ts**

```
predict() {
   if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
  // Create a new
  const worker = new Worker('../workers/model.worker', { type: 'module' });
  worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    console.log(Array.from(data.dataSync()));
  };
  worker.postMessage({tensor, model: this._model});
  } else {
    // Web Workers are not supported in this environment.
    // You should add a fallback so that your program still executes correctly.
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `how can I reference to tensorflow to use it's functions` ?

Comment: Like tf is not recognized by the compiler and throws an error. Even if I include tensorflow with importscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data exchanged between the main worker and child workers whould be serializable. Therefore, you cannot pass the model itself nor a tf.tensor. You can on the other hand pass the data and construct the tensor in your workers.

For the compiler to know that you imported a global variable, you need to declare `tf`

```
declare let tf: any // or find better type
```

Comment: Declaring the variable doesn't seem to work. I declared and called for example tf.ones([2,2]) and this is the error I got: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ones' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, it is a declare statement. Could you try it again ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't postMessage custom objects' methods, so you'd need to initialize this `model` *tensor* from the Worker itself so that it has all its methods.

To do that, if you do generate your *tensor* from a DOM element, you would first need to generate the tensor through `tf.browser.fromPixels()` from the main thread, then extract the tensor's data as a TypedArray that you will send to your Worker. Then in the Worker you will be able to create a new *tensor* instance from that TypedArray.

Here is a rewrite of the [mobilenet example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mobilenet) using a Worker, (the prediction results may take some time to appear).

```js
onload = async (evt) => {
  const worker = new Worker( getWorkerURL() );
  const imgElement = document.querySelector('img');
  // get tensor as usual
  const img = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgElement);
  // extract as TypedArray so we can transfer to Worker
  const data = await img.data();
  img.dispose();
  // wait for the Worker is ready
  // (strange bug in Chrome where message events are lost otherwise...)
  worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
    // do something with the results
    worker.onmessage = ({ data }) =>
      showResults(imgElement, data);
    // transfer the data we extracted to the Worker
    worker.postMessage(data, [data.buffer]);
  };
}
function showResults(imgElement, classes) {
  const predictionContainer = document.createElement('div');
  predictionContainer.className = 'pred-container';

  const imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
  imgContainer.appendChild(imgElement);
  predictionContainer.appendChild(imgContainer);

  const probsContainer = document.createElement('div');
  for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row';

    const classElement = document.createElement('div');
    classElement.className = 'cell';
    classElement.innerText = classes[i].className;
    row.appendChild(classElement);

    const probsElement = document.createElement('div');
    probsElement.className = 'cell';
    probsElement.innerText = classes[i].probability.toFixed(3);
    row.appendChild(probsElement);

    probsContainer.appendChild(row);
  }
  predictionContainer.appendChild(probsContainer);

  document.body.prepend(predictionContainer);
}
function getWorkerURL() {
  const elem = document.querySelector("[type='worker-script']");
  const data = elem.textContent;
  const blob = new Blob( [ data ], { type: "text/javascript" } );
  return URL.createObjectURL( blob );
}
```

```css
.pred-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pred-container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- ### worker.js ### -->
<script type="worker-script">
// we need to load tensorflow here
importScripts("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js");
(async ()=> {
const MOBILENET_MODEL_PATH =
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_0.25_224/model.json';

const IMAGE_SIZE = 224;
const TOPK_PREDICTIONS = 10;

// load the model
// note that 'tf' is available globally thanks to 'importScripts'
const mobilenet = await tf.loadLayersModel(MOBILENET_MODEL_PATH);

// let the main thread know we are ready
// (strange bug in Chrome where message events are lost otherwise...)
postMessage("ready");
self.onmessage = async ( { data } ) => {
  const img = tf.tensor(data);
  const logits = tf.tidy(() => {
    const offset = tf.scalar(127.5);
    // Normalize the image from [0, 255] to [-1, 1].
    const normalized = img.sub(offset).div(offset);

    // Reshape to a single-element batch so we can pass it to predict.
    const batched = normalized.reshape([1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3]);
    return mobilenet.predict(batched);
  });

  // Convert logits to probabilities and class names.
  const classes = await getTopKClasses(logits, TOPK_PREDICTIONS);
  postMessage(classes);
}
async function getTopKClasses(logits, topK) {
  const values = await logits.data();

  const valuesAndIndices = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    valuesAndIndices.push({value: values[i], index: i});
  }
  valuesAndIndices.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.value - a.value;
  });
  const topkValues = new Float32Array(topK);
  const topkIndices = new Int32Array(topK);
  for (let i = 0; i < topK; i++) {
    topkValues[i] = valuesAndIndices[i].value;
    topkIndices[i] = valuesAndIndices[i].index;
  }

  const topClassesAndProbs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < topkIndices.length; i++) {
    topClassesAndProbs.push({
      // would be too big to import https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/mobilenet/imagenet_classes.js
      // so we just show the index here
      className: topkIndices[i],
      probability: topkValues[i]
    })
  }
  return topClassesAndProbs;
}

})();
</script>

<!-- #### index.html ### -->
<!-- we need  to load tensorflow here too -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<img crossorigin src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/Katri.jpg/577px-Katri.jpg" width="224" height="224">
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I cannot use the reference to tf imported with importScripts. The compiler doesn't recognize it and throws an error.

Comment: That would be an other issue... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774039/how-to-import-a-node-module-inside-an-angular-web-worker maybe, but I'm really not into angular